# Remove a decimal place in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, decimal, floor

In PHP, I am getting numbers from  a database with 3 decimal places. I want to remove the last decimal point. So 2.112 will become 2.11, 23.123 will become 23.12 and 123.267 will become 123.26. Its like doing a floor at a decimal level.

Comment: Using number_format or round a number like 534.386 will become 534.39. I want it to become 534.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `number_format`, you specify the number of decimal places as the second arugment.

Example

```
$number = 534.333;

echo number_format($number,2) // outputs 534.33
```

Or use `round`

```
$number = 549.333;
echo round($number, 2) // outputs 534.33
```

Seems like `substr` is what solved the question in the end

```
substr($number,0,-1); // everything besides the last decimal
```

Comment: Using number_format a number like 534.386 will become 534.39. I want it to become 534.38.

Comment: So you just want to remove the last digit, something like `substr($number,0,-1);` will work fine in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $a = floor($a*100)/100;
```

So you can do something like that:

```
<?php

    // Note might overflow so need some checks
    function round_floor($number, $decimals) {
      $n = pow(10, $decimals);
      return floor($number * $decimals)/$decimals;
    }

    echo round_floor(2.344, 2); // Would output 2.34
    echo round_floor(2.344, 1); // Would output 2.3
```

Another option if numbers are large:

```
<?php
    // $decimal should be positive
    function round_floor($number, $decimals) {
        $a = strstr($number, '.', true);
        $b = strstr($number, '.');
        return $a . substr($b, 0, $decimal -1);
    }
```