# Drop decimal place without rounding value

Tags: php, rounding

I have a decimal value of length 15,4 in my database.

I have a number -23.425 I am trying to round down to -23.42

I have tried the following ways but they all seem to round up to -23.43:

```
 sprintf("%.2f", $discountQueryResult['value'])

 floor($discountQueryResult['value']*100)/100
```

Is there any other way to drop the 3rd decimal place?

Comment: even in excel when i decrease digits on the cell including 23.425 it changes to 23.43

Comment: Keep in mind, that floating point numbers can't necessarily represent decimal digits precisely like this. You many want to use exact types instead. Have a look at https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to round a **negative** number. Rounding *down* a negative number with [`floor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) will *increase* its absolute value; remember, `-23.43(0)` is *less* than `-23.425`!

Instead, you're looking to round *up* its value with [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php):

```
echo ceil(-23.425 * 100) / 100; // -23.42
```

This can be seen working [here](https://3v4l.org/1Mu9h).

Comment: You probably mean `absolute`, not `decimal`

Comment: @Nick - I do indeed, though the word had completely escaped me. Fixed; thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
return $rounded = 0.01 * (int)($number * 100);
```

There are other answers here like following

1) [PHP dropping decimals without rounding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079158/php-dropping-decimals-without-rounding-up)

2) [PHP: get number of decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits)

3) [Remove a decimal place in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301121/remove-a-decimal-place-in-php)